# Access to the path C:\AR\... 'file' is denied sharepoint

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

Im creating files from a sharepoint project on C drive in a particular folder. I have added the following permission rights to that folder, the code works fine and write files on specified folder. But when I deployed the same project on server and doing the same job the error occurs "Access is denied to the path C:\AR\downloadedFiles". Googled a lot but found the reason of permissions.. which i have already given.

Users to which permissions are given:

EveryOne, IUSR, INTERACTIVE, ADMINISTRATOR, SYSTEM, NETWORK ,NETWORK SERVICES, LOCAL SERVICES

Need for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){}); worked but not resolved my problem completely. I was accessing a folder in C: drive through sharepoint that was making problem. Now i am accessing a user temp folder with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges that works fine.

Thanx for help :)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    //Code used to write to file system goes here
});
```

This basically elevates the permission of the current user to the account that is running the application pool

Comment: What is the identity of the application pool that is running that sharepoint webapplication? Have you checked that that user has permissions on the folder?

Comment: Yes I have checked the permission. I provided the permissions i have mentioned above.